# Visualizing a Business Object's history

Tags: visualization

My current project has business objects that change over time. The objects can have future changes as well as past changes. One of my tasks is to create viewers and editors for these objects that let the user see its state at any point in the past or future.
The changes are fairly simple: one or more property values changed/will change on a certain date.

I'd like to give the user a simple way to see this. At minimum I need to allow the user to roll forward and back through the object's history. I'd also like to show the previous/next values (if any) of each property if I could do that without getting too cluttered or distracting. And finally, it would be cool if there was some visual way to show the complexity of the object's history, e.g., a "timeline" or something.
This is C# 3.5 on Windows forms or WPF.
All ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

One more thing: are there any patterns or best practices for coding objects with a time dimension?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts which may or may not help, since I think I'm sort of projecting my own projects onto your questions...

If the data is numerical, consider graphical representation using a charting component. Users love charts.

I work a lot with time data that can be revised over time. So imagine you have a case of beer, and you're planning on it's consumption over the week. As you go through the week and measure your actual consumption, you may need to revise your plan for the rest of the week:
[alt text http://www.sulix.com/beergraph.png](http://www.sulix.com/beergraph.png)

so the earlier assumptions get skinnier and lighter as they recede in time. Of course, depending on the nature of your data, this may not apply.

If you haven't already, check out the visualization books by Tufte. They're useful for spurring thoughts. Especially nice is [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi)

Also if the time dimension is strong, use UTC to avoid issues surrounding Daylight Saving Time (assuming you're in a location where it's in effect). Converting to "local time" in the UI is easier than trying to store it and account for DST.

As for best practices for coding time-series data, I think it depends heavily on their nature. If they're more typical "business" entities (like a person) then I'd store the versioned data in the DB, and in your DAL provide a way to fetch an object with an "As Of Datetime" parameter, so you can see what it looked like at a certain time. If on the other hand they're something like hourly traffic counts on a street, it would probably make more sense to have a "street" object which has a collection of "daily traffic counts".

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you're talking about is having a "meta-object"; that is, some object which keeps track of your business objects and which provides a consistent way to query for past and current values of state.  In general, this involves having a strong data description of your "business objects", which really turns them into business data.  Effectively, what you're talking about is simply migrating what you consider to be "business objects" into the "business data" end of things.  It's certainly possible; I'd suspect that just this change in perspective may assist you with the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the cleanest examples of what your trying to accomplish can be found right here at stackoverflow. Viewing the history of your answer edits.